# restrict length of outline entry

Tags: layout, typst

Some of my figures have long captions, which results in ugly outlines.

[image: long outline entry]

Is there a way to either truncate the `outline.entry` text, set a maximum width for the text length or trigger a linebreak after N characters, such that the `outline.entry` would compile to this:

[image]

I inspected the [source](https://github.com/typst/typst/blob/b1256283da047fd4e2c0ba24d981759c745661bb/crates/typst/src/model/outline.rs#L489) and managed to modify the part after the section title with `show outline.entry: set box(...)` but I couldn't figure out how to access what comes before the `BoxElem`.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed construct your own `outline.entry` show rule in typst instead of rust. The key ingredient is `clip: true` on the box surrounding `it.body`:

```
#show outline.entry: it => {
  style(styles => {
    let line-height = 1em
    // "columns" width determines how much of the caption should show
    grid(columns: (2fr, 1fr))[
      #box(it.body, height: line-height, clip: true)
    ][
      #box(width: 1fr, it.fill)
      #box(it.page)
    ]
  })
}
#outline(target: figure)

#figure(caption: [#lorem(150)])[
  A figure
]
```

[image]